# Create index if not exists with locks in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, locking

I have a code statement related with index creating

```
create index if not exists foo_table_index_any_id on paublic.foo_table (any_id);
```

Will the table be locked exclusively if the index has been already created there?

Comment: No, if the index already exist `if not exists` will simply stop the error message from showing and make the whole `create index` statement get ignore like it never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it takes an exclusive lock, at least in Postgres 15.3.

Client 1:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int);
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON foo(id);
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
```

Client 2:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS foo_idx ON foo(id);
-- hangs awaiting ExclusiveLock
```

Rolling back the transaction in client 1 gives the `NOTICE:  relation "foo_idx" already exists, skipping` message in client 2.

`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS foo_idx on foo(id)` goes through immediately.